# Fortify SSC Doesn't Update Audit Issues

Tags: jenkins, fortify

All,

I have a Jenkins server setup which automatically runs Fortify and uploads it to SSC. Unfortunately, SSC seems to have stopped updating.

I can see the artifact in the artifacts table and I have to manually approve it, as always, due to a "missing external metadata" issue. However, when I go to "audit issues", the issue count isn't update. If I download the project file, the appropriate number of issues is shown in the desktop application.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What version of SSC are you using?

Are you giving SSC enough time to update its metrics.  There are certain actions that require SSC to recalculate metrics.  Normally the recalculations are done at midnight.  There is an indicator that an update needs to be done (and can be triggered manually).

In the HTML SSC interface (introduced in 4.40) you will see two yellow arrows in a circle (thing of a refresh icon).  That is letting you know recalculations need to be done.  This is also a button that can be pressed to kick it off now.

In the older flash UI, when looking at the details page of a project version, there can be a Refresh button, if this is visible it means a recalculation needs to be done, either at the scheduled time or can be triggered manually.

**Side Note**

To get around the "missing external metadata" issue, you need to update the rulepacks on the SSC Server.  You can do this in the Rulepacks section of the Admin area.

Comment: I did solve the "external metadata" issue. I am now updating my Jenkins scan directly from the SSC server. We are on 4.30.0086. I'll update to 4.4.